# Copy list of files to text file, but exclude new text file

Tags: cmd.exe

I know how to create a list of text files, e.g. with `dir /b > ls.txt`

However, this always also lists the new text file (in this example, "ls.txt").
Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following command to compute the `dir` result before writing the file:

```bat
for /f %f in ('dir /b') do echo %f >>ls.txt
```

The file `ls.txt` must be non-existent or empty.